# ¿Cómo obtener los caracteres de un String?

Tags: java

Buenos días, me gustaría saber como puedo sacar cada una de las letras de una palabra, ya que se creo un vector con esa longitud y yo quiero guardar cada letra en cada espacio del vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase **String** te provee de un método que te servirá para automáticamente darte ese vector con cada letra:

```
String.toCharArray();
```

Donde "String" es la variable que contiene la cadena. Este método te generará un vector de tipo **char[ ]**.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String palabra = "Hola mundo";
    char[] caracteres = palabra.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("El caracter " + i + " es " + caracteres[i]);
    }
}
```

El resultado generado es:

```
El caracter 0 es H
El caracter 1 es o
El caracter 2 es l
El caracter 3 es a
El caracter 4 es  
El caracter 5 es m
El caracter 6 es u
El caracter 7 es n
El caracter 8 es d
El caracter 9 es o
```

Comment: Gracias es justo lo que buscaba :D

Comment: Perfecto @OscarVargasGarcia , recuerda marcar la pregunta como respondida. :)

Comment: @C.Rodriguez ayudenos a que los OP mejoren sus preguntas, y tus respuestas puedan ser de utilidad no solo al que pregunta si no a varios otros desarrolladores.

Comment: @Jorgesys, entendido y anotado :). Lo tendré muy presente en publicaciones futuras.

Answer (score 3):

Otra opción que puedes realizar es:

```
public static void main(String []args){
String x = "Palabra";
int y = x.length();
   for(int i=0;i<y;i++){
      System.out.println(x.charAt(i));
   }
}
```